# Android Emulator does not appear

Tags: android

```
[2014-03-15 11:53:53 - yellow] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***When I run the android application I get these all statements and then it stops. Emulator does not appear***

Comment: Delete emulator and create new then run. Hope work this time.

Comment: Oh!! The problem is emulator then you have to just delete your old emulator and create new emulator and launch it.

Comment: May I know how to delete it?